Python/QT and VideoPlayer replaying at end of media
Currently, I am trying to loop a video after it has finished using PySide6/Qt. The way I'm currently doing it is that I am sniffing at the mediaStatusChanged signal, and when that signals MediaStatus.EndOfMedia, I call play() on my QMediaPlayer instance.
The code looks something like this:
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        filename = "file:fnord.mp4"

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()

        self.fhnd = QtCore.QUrl(filename)

        self.player.setSource(self.fhnd)
        self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.videoWidget)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click Me")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)
        self.player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.state_change)


    @QtCore.Slot()
    def state_change(self, state):
        print("StateChange: ", state)

        #if state == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.StoppedState:
        if state == QMediaPlayer.MediaStatus.EndOfMedia:
            self.player.play()
            
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def magic(self):
        self.player.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800,600)

    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


I can start the video through the QPushButton, and it plays perfectly. At the end of the video, it stops, the state changes to EndOfMedia ( The foobar prints in my output ), but for some reason  I cannot figure out, the self.player.play() does not do anything. If I then click the button again, it starts to play.
I tried multiple things. I tried connecting to the PlaybackStateChanged, and the StoppedState and that would not work.

If you just want to play the media in loop, why don't you use QMediaPlayer.setLoops(-1)?

Note that there's almost always no point in slot-decorating connected functions, unless: 1. you have special cases related to complex threading; 2. you have huge amounts of connected QObjects that require high performance; 3. you need QMetaObject inspection for dynamically created objects; 4. you create widget classes that are used in custom Qt Designer plugins.

It would be possible. The reason for the somewhat complicated scheme is the following flow: 1) I want to start and pause the video some frames into playing. Then the program is polling some external devices for distance measuring. If it detects something close by play the video, and at the end of the video go back to the first couple of frames. This being the season of halloween couple this with a spooky video, and you can see where it goes ;)

Please don't add further explanation or code in comments. Instead, take your time to carefully [edit] your post and also ensure that you properly format code by checking the post preview before submitting the update.

As said, please [edit] your post, clarify the problem and provide a more comprehensive [mre].

The example is clearly invalid, since it doesn't connect anything to mediaStatusChanged. When connected, it works perfectly fine on Linux using the default ffmpeg backend. I suppose you could try QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.player.play) - but I don't really see why it should be needed. Anyway, this is all moot without a proper [mre]. (PS: you should also add os.environ['QT_LOGGING_RULES'] = '*.multimedia.*=true' to the top of the script to show which backend is being used).
